# Is there a way to have an inline event handler which will be executed as soon as the element has been created?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events, innerhtml

I tried `onload`, but it doesn't work:

```
var divElement = document.createElement('div');
divElement.innerHTML = '<div onload="alert(this)"></div>';
```

What "on" handler can I use to achieve this using inline Javascript?

Comment: what is the purpose of the handler?

Comment: you can have a look at mutationobserver

Comment: As soon as the element is created I want to execute a function in which I'll use the 'this' keyword to act upon that exact div.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do this in JQuery. I have mentioned following code snippet. Click on "Run Code Snippet" to get demo of code.

```js
$( "#book" ).load(function() {
   
  alert('element loaded')
  $(this).addClass("imgHeight")
});
```

```css
.imgHeight{ height:150px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://quadrobay.com/quadrobay/images/fsolution.png" alt="Book" id="book">
```